# Building Mozilla on Ubuntu Freezes My Machine

Tags: 16.04, compiling, mozilla

I have followed all instructions on getting all dependencies for Mozilla to start to contribute as developer as described on the website.  I also got the source code on my machine but when I try to run

```
./mach build
```

from the mozilla-central directory as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Simple_Firefox_build/Linux_and_MacOS_build_preparation). The issue is that every time I try to build my computer starts to get very slow and then eventually freezes up after after 1 to 6 minutes and I am forced to do a cold boot.  This has happened 4 times now. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 with 4GB RAM.